# Div with id exists but not recognised by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have a page which loads another into a div every 5 seconds.
I use jQuery to load it on document.ready which works but doesn't reload every 5 seconds when the setInterval function gets called.
 I get the error **`"Cannot read property 'load' of null"`**

```
<div id="wallboard"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">     
    $(document).ready(function(){
     //Put in initial data THIS WORKS
     $('#wallboard').load('refresh_wall2_test.php'); 

        //Refresh wallboard div every 5 seconds THIS DOESN'T WORK
        $(function(){ 
            window.setInterval(
            function(){                     
                $('#wallboard').load('refresh_wall2_test.php'); 
            } ,5000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `$(function()..` is shorthand for `$(document).ready()..`. Don't call it twice.

Comment: `setInterval` will keep queueing ajax calls when earlier calls haven't completed. But it looks like the issue really is `refresh_wall2_test.php`.

Comment: even selector does not match any element, jQuery never returns `null`, so are you sure $  still refers to jQuery? BTW, on which browser do you get this error message?

Comment: Sounds like in fact your loaded script include prototypejs or any other lib overwritting $ and returning null

Comment: A. Wolff that's what it was I've found that my refresh_wall2_test.php file was including prototype and conflicting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `setInterval` at the first place. All you need to do is to wait for the first load to complete, in the complete callback, do a `setTimeout` which would reload the `div` with the set delay. Hope that helps.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Store the reference
    var $elem = $('#wallboard');
    //Create a named self executing function
    (function loadPage() {
        $elem.load('refresh_wall2_test.php', function() {
            //When the request is complete, do a timeout which calls the function again.
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                loadPage();
            }, 5000);
        });
    }());
});
```

Comment: @swdee It is really confusing how this would fix your issue regarding error message. More sounds like you were overwritting $ alias inside the loaded script, maybe using jQuery noConflict method

Comment: I've found that my refresh_wall2_test.php file was including prototype and conflicting with jQuery! Still not sure how the above got round this issue though

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(function(){ 
    $('#wallboard').load('refresh_wall2_test.php'); 
    window.setInterval(
        function(){                     
            $('#wallboard').load('refresh_wall2_test.php'); 
        } ,5000);
    });
})();
```

Comment: I still get "Cannot read property 'load' of null"

Comment: does the page exist?

Comment: Yes the page exists, LShetty's answer worked, don't know why though

Answer (score 1):

Define the function outside of document.ready and call the setInterval in there.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(foo(page), 5000);
});
var foo = function(page) {
    $('#wallboard').load(page);
};
```

Comment: The page doesn't refresh at all

Comment: Sorry, I had an extra parentheses at the end. This solution is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly for me. I put your setInterval function on a variable, so if needed, you can `clearInterval`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        "use strict";
        
        // Load the window on ready...
        $('#wallboard').load('home.php');

        //Refresh wallboard div every 5
        window.reloadDiv = window.setInterval(
            function () {
                $('#wallboard').load('refresh_wall2_test.php');
        }, 5000);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wallboard"></div>
```

Comment: I still get "Cannot read property 'load' of null"

Comment: My guess is that you are having an error somewhere else on the page. Using the script I gave alone in an .html file will yield the correct results. Could you post your whole (or nearly) document?